# How to exclude folders from gallery?

Tags: onedrive

I use OneDrive for many things and there are images everywhere outside the Pictures folder.

OneDrive shows them in the Gallery (Photos > Gallery > All Photos) which is useless and makes working with the actual pictures that I care more difficult.

Is it possible to exclude everything but the Pictures folder so when I open the Gallery I see my photos and not random crap?

Comment: See if the last entry in [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/onedrive/comments/deq21g/exclude_certain_folders_from_adding_pictures_to/) is useful to you.

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot. do you want to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: Couldn't you just put a `.` (period) in the front of the folder name?  E.g., `.yourfolder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Redit post
[Exclude certain folders from adding pictures to photos](https://www.reddit.com/r/onedrive/comments/deq21g/exclude_certain_folders_from_adding_pictures_to/)
contains this method that worked for the poster:

> Near the upper right, there is a descending hamburger icon that shows up as "Show photos from", click on that and select "Pictures". If your comic pictures or whatever are in a folder, just move that folder to the Documents section of one drive and they will no longer appear in the All Photos section.